# Why are these shared libs not being found by ld?

Tags: gcc, ld, autotools, automake, libtool

My automake builds used to build fine, but not since I did a large update to my gentoo box which did update binutils. I am now running binutils-2.23.2.

The share libraries are building, but when it comes time to link with the program, the linker is not finding the libs, however, these libraries do exist in the .libs dir of each of the library directories and are added to _LDADD and the paths are in _LDFLAGS.

Here's the compile output till the error:

```
...  
/bin/sh ../../../libtool --tag=CXX   --mode=link g++  -std=gnu++0x -L/usr/lib64 -L/usr/local/lib64 -L/usr/local/lib -L/home/srd/ODDS/ACE_wrappers/lib -L/home/srd/ODDS/DDS/lib -L/home/srd/ODDS/DDS/dds/DCPS -L/home/srd/staging/test-BUILD/src/libs/conidl -L/home/srd/staging/test-BUILD/src/libs/common  -o econ econ-listener.o econ-main.o -lboost_program_options -lOpenDDS_Tcp -lOpenDDS_InfoRepoDiscovery -lOpenDDS_Dcps -lTAO_PortableServer -lTAO_AnyTypeCode -lTAO -lACE -lboost_thread -lrt -lboost_system -lpthread -leconf -lecommons  
libtool: link: g++ -std=gnu++0x -o econ econ-listener.o econ-main.o  -L/usr/lib64 -L/usr/local/lib64 -L/usr/local/lib -L/home/srd/ODDS/ACE_wrappers/lib -L/home/srd/ODDS/DDS/lib -L/home/srd/ODDS/DDS/dds/DCPS -L/home/srd/staging/test-BUILD/src/libs/conidl -L/home/srd/staging/test-BUILD/src/libs/common -lboost_program_options -lOpenDDS_Tcp -lOpenDDS_InfoRepoDiscovery -lOpenDDS_Dcps -lTAO_PortableServer -lTAO_AnyTypeCode -lTAO -lACE -lboost_thread -lrt -lboost_system -lpthread -leconf -lecommons  
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.7.3/../../../../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/ld:
cannot find -leconf  
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.7.3/../../../../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/ld:
cannot find -lecommons  
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status  
make[4]: *** [econ] Error 1
```

I've tried adding these two libs to _LDADD multiple times and in different orders, but it hasn't made a difference other than the ordering of the error. The Makefile.am for this program is:

```
include $(top_srcdir)/common.am

bin_PROGRAMS = econ  

econ_SOURCES = listener.cpp main.cpp  

econ_CPPFLAGS = -I$(top_srcdir)/src/includes -I/usr/include/boost -I/usr/local/include -I$(ACE_INCL) -I$(DDS_HOME) -I$(TAO_INCL) -I$(TAO_INCL)/orbsvcs -I$(top_srcdir)/src/libs/conidl  

econ_LDFLAGS = -L/usr/lib64 -L/usr/local/lib64 -L/usr/local/lib -L$(ACE_LIBS) -L$(DDS_LIBS) -L$(DCPS_LIBS) -L$(E_LIBS)/conidl -L$(E_LIBS)/common

econ_LDADD = -lboost_program_options -lOpenDDS_Tcp -lOpenDDS_InfoRepoDiscovery  -lOpenDDS_Dcps -lTAO_PortableServer -lTAO_AnyTypeCode -lTAO -lACE               -lboost_thread -lrt -lboost_system -lpthread -leconf -lecommons
```

The common.am included in the Makefile.am looks like this:

```
E_HOME = /home/srd/staging/test-BUILD  
E_LIBS = $(E_HOME)/src/libs
```

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: g++ doesn't look in .libs directories because none were passed to it. Normally libtool does the right thing when you pass it /path/to/libyourlib.la and not any -l and -L options, otherwise there's no point in using libtool!

Comment: Then I guess I don't understand, how do I pass /path/to/libmylib.la without using -l and -L options? I took those out and of course everything was undefined refs. I've always had to add the libs with -l and -L and its always worked for me. I don't know why it stopped working.

Comment: I don't know why and how exactly it worked before. A bit pointless to discuss what can't be reproduced. If you want to work with libtool I suggest reading its documentation. You will see that you need either /path/to/libmylib.la or -l/-L fir each individual library, you will see these two methods work differently, and you will see how .lib works together with /path/to/libmylib.la but not with -l/-L. It's all in the documentation.

Comment: If you look at the examples, you'll see that I already have those included (the -l/-L for each library).

Comment: If your libraries are in `/foo/bar/.libs`, then you must use `-L /foo/bar/.libs`, not `-L /foo/bar` (but then why use libtool at all if you are not passing it `.la` files?)